# How Could An Antarctic Society Import Everything They Need For An Average Lifestyle?

Tags: survival, modern-age, daily-life

My question is such: in a modern town or city in antartica, what would people produce/sell in order to import the other things they do not have yet?

In this hypothetical city, people can get water and food easily enough, but shelter and materials would be harder to find or forage.

The main point being: Is there enough wealth and work to have an average quality of life?

To narrow it down, let's talk about basic resource production. Unless you can see advanced production being plausible or easier than any other climate, stick to the basics, raw resources, if you please.

And no, enslaving penguins is not a natural resource. :)

Comment: What tech level is this city? How many people live there?

Comment: Are you asking for a geologic survey?

Comment: Good question. What part of Antarctica? I imagine the Peninsular, but the answer may vary by location.

Comment: Mining is the only commercially viable option. Other options (research, military) would provide only a limited and very custom source of supply.

Comment: @sphennings Modern era, (atomic era if you play civ), think Donald Trump makes things great again type era.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt No, that much information is on Wikipedia, Its open ended, if you can think of a creative way for the Antarticians to produce wealth by all means say so!

Comment: @Alexander Its all theoretical so make what you can out of it.  Sure they can mine, but can they mine enough to survive and have any sort of Quality of Life? The answer lies within your imagination.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Otto*! Interesting question. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: One hypothetical use mentioned for the Antarctic is would be as a launch site for spacecraft that would be unacceptable near populated areas. Think any type of nuclear propulsion. Not even the penguins really care if some Antarctic valley glows in the dark. Another benefit is that since the wind patterns are predictable it is possible to predict and minimize the spread of pollution.

Comment: @VilleNiemi you bring up A great point, this could also be used for things like large nuclear plants or things that are more dangerous near populous areas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bitcoin mining**

Some regions in Antarctica, like [McMurdo Dry Valleys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McMurdo_Dry_Valleys) are subjected to very strong catabatic winds, reaching speeds of 320 kilometres per hour (200 mph). These winds can be harnessed as a power source which can power up the city and provide energy for a power-intensive industry.

Criptocurrency mining is known for its high energy demand, and remote Antarctic location is ideally suited for large scale mining operations. These  operations can provide a source of revenue in the amount of hundreds of millions and even billions of dollars, which would translate to a very high standards of living for as many as 100,000 inhabitants.

Comment: This assumes Cryptocurrencies continue to function that way (by no means a certainty) and continue to hold their massive valuations (highly unlikely).  However, your answer works for any sort of power intensive computation, which will always be something we need.  I know lots of data centers are based in northern Norway where there's cheap power.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for solving the power issue, this could be helpful for the Antarticans

Comment: Interesting side effect: You also save some power, namely for cooling of your hardware.

Comment: Yep, cooling your hardware is a big thing. Don't limit this answer to bitcoins. You can perform all sorts of high performance computing here. This is already sort of a trend with big companies like Facebook putting data centers in far northern areas like Norway

Answer (score 3):

As I see it, your question is about *industry*; what goods or services can an Antarctic town **produce** in order to trade with other communities?

Realistically agriculture can't happen there, certainly not on a competitive scale and most production would be designed to feed the locals, not produce an export market. That really leaves you with 3 options.

1) Mining
As I understand it, there are a lot of mineral resources in Antarctica, although I don't have specifics to hand. This is however more problematic than you may think. Antarctica is protected by international treaties that prevent exploitation. The minute one country violates that agreement, the others swoop in, and start digging up this pristine environment. That could be a problem for the ice for one, and that also means that there could be environmental impacts.

2) Research
At present, most settlements in Antarctica are there for research purposes. Let's say (for instance) that one of these settlements declares independence and sells research time in their settlement. This research would be an industry; sure. BUT, the problem is that scientists are a frugal lot (research grants don't spread as far as you may think) and if another area of Antarctica is still controlled by its owning territory and is prepared to support scientists more or less for free, they'll all go there instead.

3) Tourism
This to me seems like the most viable solution. There are a lot of people who'd like to visit Antarctica, take tours of the place, see the old research outposts, etc. Extreme tourism (dangerous because of the cold), eco-tourism (last pristine environment), even historical tourism (the Mawson, Scott, etc. expeditions) could all be accommodated. This type of industry is even the basis for Kim Stanley Robinson's novel Antarctica.

So there are options, tourism being the most practical and viable, but as to *how* viable, it would depend on the size of the town, how many resources (as a percentage) they can dedicate to this industry and how much external 'stuff' they really need to keep their home environment in good repair.

Comment: On the National agreements, if an independent society claimed it as their own, ignoring the agreements/treaties that are in place, what would keep them from doing so?

Comment: Probably nothing, but then if they wanted to keep it against all comers, that would just add military hardware to their list of things they need to trade for. Not an efficient start to their outposted nation.

Comment: Could they start by claiming to do research? Take some resources, start a small town, and work away anyways (hopefully in secret).

Comment: They could certainly try, but the trouble with this kind of secret is it has a nasty way of getting out; too many people know the true intent. That said, if they're operating purely as a research station, unless they're sitting on top of a pile of oil or something most people won't want the space so they could be largely ignored by the broader global community

Comment: So my "Oil research" uses the remaining oil to "fund" our research? sounds like a plan to me :D